# Pycharm выдаёт ошибку импорта

Tags: python, django, pycharm, импорт

[image: Скрин]

Подчеркивается ошибкой хотя тестовый сервер запускается и всё работает как надо. На скрине внизу сообщение о запуске тестового сервера и там всё работает как если-бы всё импортировалось правильно. Путь 100% указан верно, Пробовал перезапустить IDE не помогло

Comment: @CrazyElf
Файл  views.py как и __init__.py а находится в директории testapp папка migrations свёрнута и находится вверху поэтому вам так могло показаться

Comment: Да, я был не прав. Покажите тогда `__init__.py` что ли )  Но вообще у питона с модулями как-то очень хитро всё